# Left Div should move under the right Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs: A left one with fixed width (#Sidebar) and a right one which fills out the rest of the space (#Content).
Now when i resize my viewport, i want the left div (#Sidebar) to move under the right one (#Content).

Please note, that both Sidebar and Content Divs have dynamic height in my real scenario.

This is my current Code:

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="sidebar"></div>
 <div id="content"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 #sidebar { 
 float: left; 
 background: #CCC; height: 100px;width: 100px;}

 #content {
 margin-left: 110px;
 background: #111; height: 100px;}

 @media screen and (max-width: 500px){
 #content {
 width: 100%; 
 margin-left: 0px;
 clear: both;
 }}
```

Watch it  here: http://jsfiddle.net/faz88ayh/
=> The left Div (#Sidebar) will always stay on the top.

The effect, which i want can be achieved with bootstrap, but it doesnt support a combination of fixed and fluid width columns.
=>http://jsfiddle.net/faz88ayh/1/
(You have to resize the Results Window to see the effect)

Please help!

Comment: you should use `position:absolute;` for that.

Comment: @ketan could you show me in my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/faz88ayh/) how position:absolute would do the job? Thank you :)
PS: The #Content and #Sidebar is not fixed height in the real scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Change in css as defind in fiddle

```
#sidebar {
float: left;
background: #CCC;
height: 100px;
width: 100%
}
#content {
background: #111;
height: 100px;
width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/faz88ayh/15/

Comment: But the left div (#Sidebar) doesnt move under the #content in your Fiddle and the Sidebar has to be fixed width.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But only when the screen-size is small. (There is no Navigation in the Sidebar, only Widgets, which look ugly on top of the content).

Answer (score 0):

[there is a another answer in the fiddle for your requirement]

```
#sidebar {
background: #CCC;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 25%;
z-index: 99;/*float:left;
*/
}
#content {
background: #111;
height: 100px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
#sidebar {
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 533px) {
#sidebar {
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/faz88ayh/16/

Comment: Both Fiddles do the job, but the inherited ´left: 25%´ attributes (from bootstrap.css) had to be removed by adding: ´left: 0%´. => http://jsfiddle.net/faz88ayh/23/

Answer (score 0):

with your css only for small screen-size

```
#sidebar {
float: left;
background: #CCC;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
#content {
margin-left: 110px;
background: #111;
height: 100px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
#sidebar {
left: 18%;
top: 0;
position:absolute;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 533px) {
#sidebar {
left: 21%;
top: 0;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
#sidebar {
left: 23%;
top: 0;
}
}
```